# Fixing data pivot/grouping with db2

Tags: db2, iseries

I have a pretty straightforward sql query that I'm running on DB2 I-series 4 which is just performing some simple joins. The issue is that my materials table has it so that multiple material/color combos can be used on each body of work. Right now I'm getting rows of every combination but I want to consolidate so that if the value of test.materials.sequence is 2 then it creates two additional columns (if there's no sequence 2 for the combination then it would just be 0 and 0 in those columns.

A working fiddle is here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u4zKAdw3H4hFLbfnzEeZS2/1

THe query:

```
    WITH ALLROWS AS(
  SELECT BOD.CODE 
         ,STM.SEQUENCE
         ,MAT.MATERIAL
         ,MAT.MAT_COLOR
    FROM SKUS SK
     INNER JOIN BODIES BOD ON SK.BODY_ID = BOD.ID
     INNER JOIN CATEGORIES PRC ON PRC.ID = SK.CATEGORY_ID
     INNER JOIN SKUS_TO_MATERIALS STM ON SK.ID = STM.SKU_ID
     INNER JOIN MATERIALS MAT ON STM.MAT_ID = MAT.ID
)
SELECT 
  CODE
  , MAX(CASE WHEN SEQUENCE = 1 THEN MATERIAL ELSE '0' END) AS MATERIAL1
  , MAX(CASE WHEN SEQUENCE = 1 THEN MAT_COLOR ELSE '0' END) AS COLOR1
  , MAX(CASE WHEN SEQUENCE = 2 THEN MATERIAL ELSE '0' END) AS MATERIAL2
  , MAX(CASE WHEN SEQUENCE = 2 THEN MAT_COLOR ELSE '0' END) AS COLOR2
FROM ALLROWS
GROUP BY CODE,MATERIAL,MAT_COLOR
order by CODE ASC;
```

This is my current result:

| CODE | MATERIAL1 | COLOR1 | MATERIAL2 | COLOR2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BodA | Fabric | Black | 0 | 0 |
| BodA | Fabric | White | 0 | 0 |
| BodA | Leather | Black | Leather | Black |
| BodA | Leather | Brown | 0 | 0 |
| BodB | Fabric | Black | 0 | 0 |
| BodB | 0 | 0 | Leather | Black |
| BodC | Leather | Brown | 0 | 0 |
| BodD | Fabric | Black | 0 | 0 |

---

This is the result I would want:

| CODE | MATERIAL1 | COLOR1 | MATERIAL2 | COLOR2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BodA | Fabric | Black | 0 | 0 |
| BodA | Fabric | White | 0 | 0 |
| BodA | Leather | Black | Leather | Black |
| BodA | Leather | Brown | 0 | 0 |
| BodB | Fabric | Black | Leather | Black |
| BodC | Leather | Brown | 0 | 0 |
| BodD | Fabric | Black | 0 | 0 |

See how BodB should be a single row

Is there a way through grouping and row-operations to achieve this?

Comment: This question was also posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74695618/db2-sql-grouping-with-condition and has an accepted answer